# Fulfill a cell with Make Model and Year when I put the VIN number in another cell (Consuming Api Vpic with Google Sheets and Google Script)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to consuming a vpic Api on Google Script with Google sheet to decode a lot of vin number in a column to fulfill other columns with Make Model and Year, but it seems like when I try to parse the json it comes in blank. Here is the example code that I'm using.

```
function MAKE3(make) {
    make = encodeURI(make);
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/decodevinvalues/" + make + "?format=json");
    var w = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    return w.Results.Make;
}
```

This is to get just the Car's Make. Can someone give me a hand, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little research, I figured it out!

```
function CarModel(carmodel) {
    carmodel = encodeURI(carmodel);
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVinValues/"+carmodel+"?format=json");
    var w = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    return w.Results[0].Model
}
```